# Cannot restore big file from azure backup because of six hours timeout

Tags: azure, backup, restore

I am trying to restore a big file (~40GB) from Azure backup. I can see my recovery point and mount it as disk drive so I can copy/paste the file I need. The problem is that the copying takes approx. 8 hours, but the disk drive (recovery point) is automatically unmounted after 6 hours and the process fails consistently. I couldn't find any setting in the backup agent to increase this slot. 
Any thoughts how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling I've found a workaround, so I'll post it here for others...
I've mounted the needed recovery point as a disk drive and started a file copy. It shows the standard Windows copy file progress dialog, which has an option of pausing. So after ~5.5 hours, just before the drive is unmounted, I paused the copy, unmounted the drive manually, mounted it again (getting another 6-hours slot), and than resumed the copy. Well, I don't think that this is how Microsoft wanted me to work, but it gets the job done.
Happy restoring!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the mount time by setting the number of hours as a higher value. 
RecoveryJobTimeOut under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Backup\Config\CloudBackupProvider”

Type is DWORD; value is number of hours.

Answer (score -1):

Try to compress a copy of the file into a .zip on the server, then download the (hopefully smaller file)

Also, if you don't mind me asking, what the heck made a 40Gig *file*?

Comment: It's backup copy, not a server. I can't zip it. And of course I compress it during the backup. And it's VM disk.